# listbox alignment issue in wp7

Tags: windows-phone-7, xaml, expression-blend

I have listbox and I am placing some labels in it.

```
 <ListBox x:Name="lstContacts">
                            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <StackPanel>
                                            <HyperlinkButton Height="30" Margin="-10,0,0,0" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Content="{Binding PhoneType, Converter={StaticResource CntctConverter}}" Style="{StaticResource HyperlinkButtonStyle}"/>
                                            <TextBlock Height="30" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Text="{Binding PhoneNumber}" Width="250" Foreground="{StaticResource TitleBrush}" Tap="lblMobile_Tap" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
                                            <TextBlock Height="30" Text="{Binding CallRate}" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Foreground="{StaticResource TitleBrush}" Margin="0,-30,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
                                    </StackPanel>
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                        </ListBox>
```

My last label should come in extreme right as i made its horizontal alignment to right.
But its coming to center. Please see snapshot

[image]

Please suggest where I am making any mistake

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your StackPanel width is 250 because of the first TextBox width value, so it looks like the second TextBlock is positoned correctly to the right.

You need to increase the width of the stackpanel by adding a Width value to it.

Comment: Sir Jon I Am Talking About Horizonatal Alignment Of My TextBlock And I Have Set It To Right. So It Will Not See Who Is Left. It Will Be Right Aligned To The Page. Width Will Not Matter. :)

Comment: Your StackPanel is sized to the content and the second TextBox is right aligned to the stackpanel not the page. Try adding <StackPanel Width="460" and it will right align.

Answer (score 0):

This has to do with the default HorizontalAlignment of the ListBox. It defaults to Left. You'll need to change it to Stretch.

```
<ListBox>
    <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
            <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
        </Style>
    </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
</ListBox>
```

Comment: Nothing Done With That Too Shawn :(

Comment: Make sure you also set the HorizontalAlignment of the StackPanel if you use it. It also defaults to Left